# Can panel with layout table be forced to add items vertically until first col full?

Tags: extjs

Can a panel with table layout of 3 columns be made to add buttons vertically into the first column until that column is full and then continue adding buttons at the top of the second column etc? tia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a bit hacky but you can use a [RadioGroup](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.RadioGroup) and put some buttons into it:

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title: 'RadioGroup Example',
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items:[{
        xtype: 'radiogroup',
        columns: 2,
        vertical: true,
        items: [
            { xtype: 'button', text: 'Item 1' },
            { xtype: 'button', text: 'Item 2' },
            { xtype: 'button', text: 'Item 3' },
            { xtype: 'button', text: 'Item 4' },
            { xtype: 'button', text: 'Item 5' },
        ]
    }]
});
```